# Slide div down when hover over other div, with timer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I searched for this but didn't find an solution that totally fixed my problem.

I got 2 divs that are over each other. Where div #2 isn't shown `(display:none)`.

Now what I want is that if I hover over div #1, div #2 slides down (open) at his current position.

Then div #2 should stay open when people are hovering over div #2, when they leave the hover status of div #2 for more then 5 seconds div #2 slides up again.

I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TxnDd/1/) to illustrate my div positions.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a third party javascript library like JQuery? That could make things easier for you.

Comment: Yea im allowed to, and i tried alot of other javascript/css3 solutions. But all require that div #2 is hidden in the side of the site and slide from the side. I want to slide it open and set timer when mouse is off div #2.

Comment: pure html/css3 solution may be possibe using css animations: http://leaverou.github.com/animatable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery to keep the code simpler. One way to do what you want is to pair a global variable with a `setTimeout` function. The timeout checks if the mouse is still out of the div after five seconds, and if so, slides it up and out of sight.

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('.showme').slideDown();
});

$('.showme').mouseout(function() {
    window.isoverdiv = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!window.isoverdiv) {
            $('.showme').slideUp();
        }
    }, 5000);
});

$('.showme').mouseover(function() {
    window.isoverdiv = true;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/TxnDd/2/

Comment: This is getting my idea, but is it possible to slide it open on hover of div #1? Cause now it opens on click. And it slides down from the top, is it possible to wrap both in an div and then slide it open from the top of that div? (Cause i would like to keep the margin-top clear).

Comment: on the first line: replace 'click' with 'hover'

Comment: Well i played with your input, and came to this: http://jsfiddle.net/TxnDd/3/ which works perfectly and is exactly what i need. Thank you alot!

Comment: @lwburk OF course, you still have a global variable ('tracker'), it's just a different kind of variable.

Comment: @mblase75 - Sure, but the shared state is then encapsulated, instead of exposed to the world. Also, you could now create multiple trackers without toggling multiple global state flags. It's not so much the presence of something in the global namespace that's an issue; it's the brittle shared state.

Comment: @lwburk Agreed, although I think OP needs to address the use of class selectors vs. ID selectors before he would tackle that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I moved div #2 into div #1 and this allowed me to do this with only css
http://jsfiddle.net/57Shn/

CSS

```
.button {width:100px; height:50px; position:fixed; background-color:blue; margin-top:30px;}
.button:hover .showme {display:block}
.showme {width:100px; height:200px; position:fixed; background-color:red; display:none; margin-top:30px;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="button">
    touch me
    <div class="showme">show me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: looking at your new comment, its clear this isnt quite what you want.  You're getting downvoted (not by me) probably because your question isn't very well written or thought out, and it seems suspiciously like you are trying to get out of figuring this out yourself.

Comment: Well it didn't really solved my problem at all, first i want it to slide, second the showme div needs to be over button div and third i want an timer on div #2 when the mouse isnt on it anymore and then slide it to close.

Answer (score 0):

CSS-only solution: (doesn't slide)

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="one">Hover</div>
    <div class="two">Hello World!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.two { display: none; }
.outer:hover .two { display: block; }
```

JS solution:

```
$(function() {
    $('.two').hide();
    $('.outer').hover(function() { $('.two').stop().slideDown(); });
    $('.outer').mouseout(function() { $('.two').stop().slideUp(); });
});
```

Comment: This be a simpler representation of the concept in my answer

Comment: Well i appreciate your input, but it really needs to slide :(.

Comment: Added a sliding JS/jQuery solution.